# Quarkus opentelemetry link to parent span on redirect

Tags: java, quarkus, trace, open-telemetry

Here is the problem - I want to see full traces linked for my flow which includes redirects and during this redirect traces lost.

I use quarkus + opentelemetry.

In the middle sometimes I have ui part which is not always mine so I could pass traceparent or any other values with cookies.

Redirect is made by another service to which we send request and can not control.

Libs used inside:

```
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-common'
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
```

What I've tried already is to create @ServerRequestFilter with higher priority and move from cookie to header traceparent -> it didn't help.

Couldn't find how to correctly create parent span from **traceparent**.

UPDATE:
Found how to link 2 spans but it seems it works not as I expected

```
SpanContext parentContext = SpanContext.create(values[1], values[2], TraceFlags.getSampled(), TraceState.getDefault());
        Span parentSpan = Span.wrap(parentContext);
        Log.infof("TRACEPARENT DATA: trace is = " + values[1] + " and span is = " + values[2]);

        Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("ui-provider-picker").setParent(Context.current().with(parentSpan)).startSpan();
        try (Scope scope = span.makeCurrent()) {
        } finally {
            span.setAttribute("test", "12345");
            span.end();
        }
```

It creates new span to main trace flow and attaches to it -> and then I have still separate trace which I wanted to link with all needed tags.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#sampler  with **parentbased_always_on** ?

Comment: well, it didn't help. Tried all  of them